# single instance of a function

Tags: c++, singleton

I'm working on a C++ Project (Embarcadero C++ Builder) where many classes (all in the same namespace) need to get color values from color names. To realize that, I created a function getColorCode() used by all Classes, in a separate piece of code, Tools.cpp, shown below:

```
#include "Tools.h"
namespace mynamespace {
int getColorCode(std::string Name)
{
  if (Name == "red") return(0xFF0000);
  else if (Name == "green") return(0x00FF00);
  else if (Name == "blue") return(0x0000FF);
  // many more else ifs
  else return(0x000000);
}
}
```

The header file is:

```
#ifndef MYNAMESPACE_TOOLS_H
#define MYNAMESPACE_TOOLS_H
#include <string>
namespace mynamespace {
  int getColorCode(std::string Name);
}
#endif
```

This works, but I would like to have all color definitions stored in a map to avoid hundreds of else ifs. My problem is, that I cannot define something like `std::map<std::string, int> ColorNames;`in the header file of Tools.cpp without getting `W8058 Cannot create pre-compiled header` at the line defining the map. In addition, I get several linker warnings that mynamespace::ColorNames is defined in every Class including Tools.h.

What I planned was to fill the map at the first call to getColorCode() by checking map.empty() and add all the color names and codes to it, if it is empty, so further calls will just search the map.

Another try was creating a tools-class for this and initialize the map in the constructor. But then every class using it creates an own instance of it, which I do not want. Reading the discussions about singletons and trying the code proposed did not help.

Is there any practical way to implement this or shoud I stay with the ugly (non performant) if-then-else chain?

Thanks for any hints, Armin

Comment: Why do you presuppose the if-then-else chain is non-performant?  Have you profiled it?  I'm sure you're taking a much bigger hit by comparing *strings* then you ever will from an if-then-else chain.  You are so barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: You need a namespace-scope variable like `std::map<std::string, int> ColprNames;` somewhere in `Tools.cpp` inside `namespace mynamespace`. Keep the `getColorCode()` function but make it using the map.

Comment: @n.m. : Thanks for your comment. I tried it combined with the similar hint from rerun below and it solves my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file level static seams to be appropriate to me here but you will need handle race conditions on initialization.  However I might suggest just create macros for the color names that get replace by the int.  Or a class that has all const memebers

A file level static

```
static std::map<string,int> Colors; 
static std::mutex lck; 
int getColorCode(std::string Name)
{
    // Get a lock here if you are not single threaded 
    lck.lock()
    if(Colors.empty())
    {...}
    lck.unlock()
}
```

or a class that has all the colors

```
class Colors 
{
    Colors():
        red(0xFF0000)
    {

    }
    int red; 
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `static std::mutex lck;`?? But nice idea to make it thread safe though!

Comment: `static` declaration within the function body would have been sufficient. For your class idea (which is also nice), you should elaborate a bit more about usage, and `int red;` should be `public: const int red` IMHO, or even simply `static const` then. But nevertheless, if the primary key is a string, the primary key is a string ...

Comment: inline static are not thread safe to initialization. So the mutex has to initialized before you enter the function.

Comment: @rerun: I added the file level solution to the code, placing the static map into the function body as g-makulik suggested. This works perfect for me. Thanks for the hint, and for bringing up the mutex to make it thread safe.

Comment: @Armin Ooop's didn't really suggested that, but it will work of course to place the map scoped to the function locally as `static`. Regarding the mutex @rerun is right. It should be placed module local (not function wise), to be initialized correctly. Sorry, I'm currently using embedded environments, where I have control over this stuff, and know what happens in detail, and may not use standardized behavior.

Comment: Ah! And put it to an unnamed namespace to have it **really** file level static (private, internal, ...). AFAIK c++ is different from c regarding that point, the linker still might see the definitions!

Comment: -1 because C++11 requires thread-safe static initialization, and you can initialize it with a lambda or initializer list to skip the whole "if colors.empty()` thing.

Comment: That's not really a reason for a downvote, but a reason to write your own answer.

Comment: If you use an initializer.  If you use assignment the initialization is thread safe and will only occur once but assignment is not.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use C++11 (I'm not familiar with C++-builder), you can initialize a static map in the function like so

```
int getColorCode(std::string name) {
    static std::map<std::string, int> colors{
        { "red",   0xFF0000 },
        { "green", 0x00FF00 },
        // ... etc
    };

    // rest of logic.
}
```

The benefit of this is that the map is localized to the function, initialized once and only once, and cannot be accessed from the outside world.

If you don't have C++11 features (again, I don't know the compiler), simply check if the map is empty like you said, and fill it. I would still mark it as static though, global variables are bad.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple `struct` declaration instead of a map. As long you wouldn't have millions of entries this shouldn't really give you a significant performance hit over using a `std::map`. Check *O(n)* vs *O(log n)* complexity if it fits for your needs for *n* entries, but I think n in the range of hundreds (as you mentioned) shouldn't be too.

Just inside your .cpp do:

```
namespace {
    struct ColorDef
    {
        std::string name;
        int colorValue;
    };

    ColorDef colorValueDefs[] = {
        // Put your entries here:
        { "red", 0xFF0000 } ,
        { "green", 0x00FF00 } ,
        { "blue", 0x0000FF } ,
        // etc. ...
        // { "" , -1 } // have an end marker if you don't want to use sizeof() 
                       // to iterate through
    };
}

namespace mynamespace {
    int getColorCode(std::string Name) {
        // Make it thread safe if necessary:
        // static std::mutex mtx;
        // std::lock(mtx);
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(colorValueDefs); ++i) {
            if(Name == colorValueDefs[i].name) {
                return colorValueDefs[i].colorValue;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

If you can use the [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) standards syntax you can initialize a `std::map` the same way as the `colorValueDefs` array shown above.

**UPDATE**
OK, I think I've been telling bullshit abut lookup performance here! If I get the diagrams correctly, the performance hit starts to emerge at very low numbers of *n*, check the diagram: [n = 10](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20f%28x%29%20=%20log%20x%20from%20x=0%20to%2010;%20plot%20f%28x%29%20=%20x%20from%20x=0%20to%2010)
I'm not sure to get the right representation for *O(n)* / *O(log n)* here though :-/ ...
`std::map` should be the better choice then performance wise! You'll get a small hit when initializing at first call of your function, or you can avoid this when initializing your map using the [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) initializer list feature.

Answer (score -1):

Just put the map in your source file and use the function to retrieve values from it:

```
#include "Tools.h"
namespace mynamespace {
    std::map<std::string, int> ColorNames;
    int getColorCode(std::string Name)
    {
       // do some error checking
       // assume ColorNames has already been populated somehow
       return ColorNames[Name];
    }
 }
```

Comment: IMHO the OP's question doesn't primarily refer to how to access the entries from the map, but how to populate it with the right values conveniently!

Comment: he is trying to have a single access point for retrieving color values, the title of the question indicates that he wants a singleton pattern of some kind for this. I dont see it as 'how do i initialize my map' kind of question